# Is this a correct use of the triangle inequality?

Tags: real-analysis

In a solution this is written:

$$\left(\sum_{n=1}^M|x_n^k-x_n|^2\right)^{0.5}=\left(\sum_{n=1}^M|x_n^k-x_n^j+x_n^j-x_n|^2\right)^{0.5}$$

$$\le \left(\sum_{n=1}^M|x_n^k-x_n^j|^2\right)^{0.5}+\left(\sum_{n=1}^M|x_n^j-x_n|^2\right)^{0.5}$$

They've used it has it was the ordinary triangle inequality, but the absolute values are squared?

edit:

I mean, we dont have:

$|a-b|^2\le |a-c|^2+|c-b|^2$, for any, a,b,c?, or do we?

Answer (score 2):

If $\rho$ is the typical Euclidean metric on $\Bbb{R}^M$ then $\rho(a,b) = \big(\sum_{n=1}^M |a_n-b_n|^2\big)^{1/2}$ and you get the triangle inequality for $\rho$, which in your case seems to be $\rho(x^k,x) \leq \rho(x^k,x^j)+\rho(x^j,x)$.

It is not true that for real $r,s\in\Bbb{R}$ that $|r-s|^2 \leq |r-t|^2+|t-s|^2$ (take e.g. $r=1, s=0, t=1/2$); however, you do have that $\sqrt{|r-s|^2} \leq \sqrt{|r-t|^2}+\sqrt{|t-s|^2}$; i.e., the square root makes a difference.

Answer (score 1):

the triangle inequality reads: if $N$ is a norm, then

$$
N(a+b) \le N(a) + N(b)
$$

Here this is the triangle inequality, with
$$
N(x) = \left[\sum_{n=1}^m x_n^2
\right]^{.5}
$$